# Removing Macro from Shape Programmatically

Tags: vba, excel

I have several "Buttons" that change dynamically with the content of the sheet. I just need to figure out 1 line of code to get it working properly (Line 3):

```
Public Sub ClearMacro(shapename As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(shapename).OnAction = Nothing
End Sub
```

I want to completely remove the macro from the shape, but keep the shape. Anything I can do differently to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Set` and `Nothing` on objects. OnAction accepts a string value, use .OnAction = "" instead.

```
Public Sub ClearMacro(shapename As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(shapename).OnAction = ""
End Sub
```